# Cypher query to check if list1 contains any item from list2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Every node in my DB has a property that holds a list. I need to check whether any item in a given list is in that property.

I'm looking for a query like `match (n) where any(x in n.list where x=[101,102,103]) return n` - which means **"check if n.list contains 101, 102, 103. If so, return n"**

Is there anything like that in cypher?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You pretty much have the answer to your question !

Check this : https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-any, the any predicate exists.

The only error in your query is `x=[101,102,103]` that you should change by `x IN [101,102,103]`

So the final query is :

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE any(x IN n.list WHERE x IN [101,102,103])
RETURN n
```